# difference between "import foo.bar" and "import foo"?

Tags: python, python-import

I just found that when I do

```
import pygame.joystick
```

I not only have access to `joystick`, but also to `display`, i.e. I can for example do

```
pygame.display.init()
```

just as if I had simply imported `pygame`.

What is the difference?

Comment: That's because `pygame.display` is a dependency imported transitively. You can't count on that happening with every package. Better import your dependencies explicitly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, that means that there is an `import pygame.display` statement in the package's initialization code?

Comment: also check the [importing submodules section of the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules) for general behaviour

Comment: @A.Donda: yes, perhaps in `pygame/__init__.py`, or `pygame.joystick` has that import, or either of these import something that then (eventually) imports `pygame.display`. An implementation detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On import, module's inner code on the top level is executed, and the module is added to `sys.modules` and made available for use. Based on what was inside the source file, anything can and may happen.

In your case, either of `pygame/__init__.py` or `pygame/joystick.py` contains:

```py
import pygame.display
```

Hence the availability of the module you weren't even trying to import.

Answer (score 5):

What's happening is that importing `pygame.joystick` triggers additional imports; either the `pygame` package itself, or `pygame.joystick`, or any of the `pygame.*` modules these two modules import, happen to import `pygame.display` somewhere.

So the fact that you can now reference `pygame.display` is an accident of implementation details. You may not be able to in future versions (if the project no longer needs to import `pygame.display` to load `pygame.joystick`, for example).

It is better to stick to an explicit import in your own project.

Answer (score 1):

In the source code of joystick, they're importing pygame.display or pygame and the sort.

In the C version of the documentation:

In the file joystick.c they've included joystick.h

```
#include <joystick.h>
```